# Return View even if model returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have hit a little snag. I have a view that has a list that is associated with the location. In this view i have an if statement:

```
@if (Model != null)
```

My controller action is this

```
 public ActionResult CustomerMachineList(int AddressId)
    {
        //Trying to get a view model for customer from the received AddressId.
        MachineList modelInstance = MachineList.ListMachinesByAddress(AddressId, db);

        return View(modelInstance);

    }
```

This is the admin area. If a customer does not put a connected record in, I go in and add it for them. The problem is that it returns null because they have not added anything. 
At the top of my view i have a button to add a record.

So my question is how do i open the view even though the model is empty or null? So that i can add if i need to. 
Below is my viewModel

```
public partial class MachineList
{
    public static MachineList ListMachinesByAddress(int id, CustomerEntities db)
    {
        var qSer = from se in db.SerialNumbersView  
                   join cus in db.CompanyNames on se.CompanyId equals cus.CompanyId
                   join ad in db.Addresses on cus.CompanyId equals ad.CompanyId
                   join anu in db.Users on ad.AddressId equals anu.AddressId
                   where (ad.AddressId == id)
                   select new MachineList()
                   {
                       AddressId = ad.AddressId,
                       CompanyId = cus.CompanyId,
                       CompanyName = cus,
                       Company = cus.CompanyName,
                       SerialNumbers = se
                   };
        var result = qSer.FirstOrDefault();

        if (result != null)
        {
            result.SerialDetail = db.SerialNumbersView.Where(a => a.AddressId == result.AddressId);

        };
        return result;
    }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public virtual SerialNumbersView SerialNumbers { get; set; }
    public virtual CompanyNames CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual TopLvlJobs Job { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<SerialNumbersView> SerialDetail { get; set; }
}
```

All code works as long as there is an associated record.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The way I do is: If the model doesn't exists in db then I create a new model in memory (not in database), initialise it and  `return View(model);`. The user gets back a form to edit the new model. When user clicks Save, I save model instance into db. Specify http verb POST as decorator in method header, so you know this is the user saving the form, not the user editing the form, which would be http GET. Try to find on line examples, I'm sure you'll get the concept quickly.

Comment: Maybe im misunderstanding but perhaps you could return a "default(T)" with T being the object type?

Comment: @derloopkat thanks, This is the admin end. So really do not need to verify anyone. On the user side it verifies with the userId. It works. This issue i am having is that it is on the Admin side and it seems that the changes i made to the ViewModel is maybe not correct. I might look at doing an if statement on the button that takes me to the view so that i do not hit that model unless there is something in there. Ill have to dig around I guess.